# Grails: How to send a closed workbook in the client?

Tags: excel, grails

Currently, I have a working code that sends excel file to the client. The only problem is that once the client receives the file, it is automically opened. I'm using org.apache for my workbook. Ans here's my code..

```
 private void generateErrorReport(ServletResponse response, Map message, MultipartFile file, String ext){
        InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = response.outputStream;

        int index = file.originalFilename.lastIndexOf(".");
        String fileName = file.originalFilename.substring(0,index) + "_error." + ext

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=${fileName}");
        try {

            PoiTransformer transformer = PoiTransformer.createTransformer(is, os);
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = transformer.getWorkbook()
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(workbook.getActiveSheetIndex())
            int lastColNum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()

            Cell cell;

            cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(lastColNum);
            if(cell==null){
                cell = sheet.getRow(0).createCell(lastColNum);
            }
            cell.setCellType(1)
            cell.setCellValue("Message")
            cell.setCellStyle(getStyle(workbook, 2))

            for(int it=1; it<sheet.getLastRowNum(); it++) {
                if (message.get(new Long(it))!=null && message.get(new Long(it))!=[]) {
                    cell = sheet.getRow(it).getCell(lastColNum);
                    if(cell==null){
                        cell = sheet.getRow(it).createCell(lastColNum);
                    }
                    cell.setCellType(1)
                    cell.setCellValue(message.get(new Long(it)).join(', '))
                    cell.setCellStyle(getStyle(workbook, 1))
                }
            }

            sheet.autoSizeColumn(lastColNum);
            transformer.write();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            println ex;
        } finally {
            closeStream(is);
            closeStream(os);
        }

    }
```

How will I stop the excel file from automatically opening when the user received it?

Answer (score 0):

According to this RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.1) the browser should open the "save a file" dialog and let the user to choose where to save the file.

My advice would be to open the dev tools (F12, Cmd Alt I) switch to network and see what headers are sent to the client when requesting the excel file.

Other things you can consider:

- set the mime type (`response.setContentType`) to `application/vnd.ms-excel`
- set the mime type `application/octet-stream`. This way you're telling the browser that the data is binary and nothing more.

Comment: I've tried to set mimetype to application/vnd.ms-excel and also to application/octet-stream but it didnt work :(

Comment: What browser do you use? Hope it's not IE6 :-) Did you have a change to check the headers in the browser (using the developers tools)?